# how to calculate the weights for deconvolution layer based on the trained value weights of the corresponding convolution layer

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

Is this possible?
The correspoding layer for deconvolution layer is tf.conv2d_transpose(), but the document states it is just a transpose conv layer, not a real deconv.
So how can I calculate the weights for deconv layers?
Like in the following codes, how can I make y == x(by calculating W2 from W)? Is this possible? Or the only way is to **train** the deconv layer?

```
# [batch, height, width, depth]
x_image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[3,2])
x = tf.reshape(x_image,[1,3,2,1])

#Filter: W  [kernel_height, kernel_width, output_depth, input_depth]
W_cpu = np.array([[-1,1]],dtype=np.float32)
W = tf.Variable(W_cpu)
W = tf.reshape(W, [1,2,1,1])

W_cpu2 = np.array([[-1,1]],dtype=np.float32)
W2 = tf.Variable(W_cpu2)
W2 = tf.reshape(W2, [1,2,1,1])

strides=[1, 1, 1, 1]
padding='VALID'

z = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=strides, padding=padding)

y = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(z, W2, [1,3,2,1],strides, padding)

x_data = np.array([[1,-1],[2,2],[1,2]],dtype=np.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)

    x = (sess.run(x, feed_dict={x_image: x_data}))
    W = (sess.run(W, feed_dict={x_image: x_data}))
    z = (sess.run(z, feed_dict={x_image: x_data}))
    y = (sess.run(y, feed_dict={x_image: x_data}))

    print("The shape of x:\t", x.shape, ",\t and the x.reshape(3,2) is :")
    print(x.reshape(3,2))
    print()

    print ("The shape of x:\t", W.shape, ",\t and the W.reshape(1,2) is :")
    print (W.reshape(1,2))
    print ("")


    print ("The shape of z:\t", W.shape, ",\t and the W.reshape(1,2) is :")
    print (z.reshape(3))
    print ("")

    print ("The shape of y:\t", y.shape, ",\t and the y.reshape(3,3) is :")
    print (y.reshape(3,2))
    print ("")
```

But in *Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks, Matthew D. Zeiler and Rob Fergus*, they proposed a way to do deconv with the"transposed
versions of the same filters*, does this mean the shape is transposed or it includes the weight?

Comment: "but the _document_ states it is just a transpose conv layer", which document?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d_transpose